# What film has been remade the most?

Tags: remake, brewsters-millions

I recently came to learn that Brewster's Millions (1985) with Richard Pryor, is only one of 13 versions adapted from the 1902 book.

What film has the most versions?

Comment: According to [this](https://www.theweek.co.uk/99568/the-29-most-remade-movies-of-all-time), Brewster's Millions has been made/remade **5** times. What have you discovered from research?

Comment: From Wikipedia: "and the novel or play has been adapted into films thirteen times, four of which were produced in India."

Comment: If you are asking about versions of a common central plot then I would put [Pygmalion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pygmalion_(1938_film)) at or near the top. I can think of more than 5 off the top of my head but don't have time to make an extensive list.

Comment: Wikipedia lists 5 film versions of Pygmalion.  It lists 21 film versions of A Christmas Carol.